How to sample point using LatinHyper Cube sampling in a random volume
I have a a dataset composed of XYZ coordinates, which can be rendered in 3D bar chart as the picture below.

The main question I have is: how to generate X points (X being a user input) inside said volume ensuring the best representation possible ?
My first approach was to use the LatinHyper Cube sampling method, but as the name suggests it supposed a cubic design space. Here the volume could be any shape.
I then tried to applied the method described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174751/generate-random-points-within-n-dimensional-ellipsoid I hoped the method could be tweaked to any shape rather the an ellipsoid. It is not the case (or at least, I failed to do so).
As a "bonus" question, I am not happy with the 3D histogram approach, I would rather have a "proper" volume. Using griddata implies a cubic base which is not the case here.
EDIT:
I managed to plot my data as a 3D surface, which is fine for my usage using the following:
data_2d = [
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 0],
    [0, 0, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 16, 18, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 16, 18, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 16, 18, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 16, 18, 0, 0],
]
# data_2d: - rows are Hs from 1 to 8 (8 rows)
#          - columns are Tp from 2 to 22 (10 columns)
#          - content is the wind speed from 2 to 22

data_array = np.array(data_2d)
x_data, y_data = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(2, 22, 11), np.linspace(1, 8, 8))


ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot_surface(x_data, y_data, data_array, cmap="viridis", edgecolor="black")
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")



I have no idea what “Hs” and “Tp” mean. Are your factors continuous, discrete, or categorical? Sampling is by nature discrete/categorical, but if your factors are continuous over the range they don’t necessarily have to be sampled at integer values.

Those are environmental conditions for waves (X - Y) plotted against wind speed (Z). These values are discrete, i don't necessarily care if I have non integer XYZ sampled point. As long as the entire volume defined by the colored surface is sampled by X random points, I am happy

Designs for continuous factors are often described in standardized ranges (generally [0,1] or [-1,1]), then scaled to the problem’s units. Randomized Latin Hypercubes are often generated on an integer grid, but then rescaled. Linear rescaling doesn’t affect the orthogonality of a good design — for example, you’re sampling the same temperatures regardless of whether you measure them in F, C, or K.

Indeed, however in my case, I do not have a "regular" range in all three dimensions. The zeros are not acual zero, I put them instead of np.nan in order to have a plot easier to see. Those are actually "exclusion zone". I do not wish to sample there, e.g. X = 5, Y = 5 produce Z = 0 means, that my randomied sampling process should exclude this area.

Sounds like you should consider a change of variables. For example, in queueing systems the queue is often thought of in terms of lambda (arrival rate) and mu (service rate). However, queues are unstable if the traffic intensity (rho = lambda / mu) exceeds 1, so experiments are generally specified in terms of rho and lambda or rho and mu to keep the traffic intensity of all experiments in the stable range. Note that your question centers on a statistical design of experiments issue, not a programming one, so it’s off-topic for stackoverflow.

Actually, I split the issue in two steps:

Generate LHS sampling in the XY plan bounded by a polygon
For each sampled draw a random Z value bounded by an arbitrary minimum value and the calculated upper Z value.

Below is a MWE for whoever would be interested:
    from random import uniform
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from scipy.interpolate import CloughTocher2DInterpolator as CT
    from scipy.stats import qmc
    from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

    data_2d = [
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 14, 16, 18, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 14, 16, 18, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 14, 16, 18, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 14, 16, 18, np.nan, np.nan],
]
# data_2d: - rows are Hs from 1 to 8 (8 rows)
#          - columns are Tp from 2 to 22 (10 columns)
#          - content is the wind speed from 2 to 22

tp_hs_ws = pd.DataFrame(data_2d)
tp_hs_ws.columns = [np.arange(2, 24, 2)]
tp_hs_ws.index = [np.arange(1, 9, 1)]
x_data, y_data = np.meshgrid(np.arange(2, 24, 2), np.arange(1, 9, 1))

non_nan_coord = [
    (2, 1),(20, 1),(22, 2),(22, 3),(22, 3),(20, 4),(18, 5),(18, 8),(14, 8),(14, 5),(12, 4),(12, 3),(10, 2),(6, 2),(2, 1)]

polygon = Polygon(non_nan_coord)
xp, yp = polygon.exterior.xy

points = LHS_Points_in_Polygon(polygon, nb_points)
xs = [point.x for point in points]
ys = [point.y for point in points]

# Keep only the unique LHS samples
xs = pd.Series(xs).unique()
ys = pd.Series(ys).unique()
xs_grid, ys_grid = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

# Interpolate initial wind speed on the LHS Hs/Tp grid
zz = []
for z in (np.array(data_2d)).ravel():
    if str(z) == "nan":
        z = 0
    zz.append(z)

xy = np.c_[x_data.ravel(), y_data.ravel()]
CT_interpolant = CT(xy, zz)
Ws = CT_interpolant(xs_grid, ys_grid)

# Select the wind speed associated to the LHS Tp/Hs samples
ws = []
for idx_tp, _ in enumerate(xs_grid.ravel()):
    ws.append(Ws.ravel()[idx_tp])
# Make the LHS samples in square matrix form
ws_LHS = np.reshape(ws, (len(xs_grid), len(ys_grid)))
# The diagonal of wind speed LHS samples is corresponding to the XY coordinates sampled
ws_LHs_diag = ws_LHS.diagonal()

# Create random wind speed between 2m/s (arbitrary lower bound) and the LSH sampled wind speed value (upper bound)
# This ensure to produce a point XYZ always contained with the voume Tp/Hs/Wind speed
random_ws = [uniform(2, ws) for ws in ws_LHs_diag]

The function LHS_Points_in_Polygon is inspired by this solution.
def LHS_Points_in_Polygon(polygon, number):
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = polygon.bounds
    sampler = qmc.LatinHypercube(d=2, scramble=False)
    sample = sampler.random(n=number)
    l_bounds = np.min((minx, miny))
    u_bounds = np.max((maxx, maxy))
    points = []
    while len(points) < number:
        for x, y in qmc.scale(sample, l_bounds, u_bounds):
            pnt = Point(x, y)
            if polygon.contains(pnt):
                points.append(pnt)
    return points

Below is the outcome:


